# P5 TypeError e is undefined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to upload images be used essentially as coins to be collected in my p5 game. However, I can't figure out how to make them appear. Part of the problem is the error "e is undefined" from p5.min.js, which is my untouched p5 code. What am I doing wrong? I just can't make them appear on screen. Here's my code (here the coins are represented as tp)

Am I completely missing something?

From tp.js:

```
    let tp
class Tp {
    constructor(y, x) {
        this.x = 500;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = 30
        this.height = 30
        this.tp = tp
    }

    preload() {
        this.tp = loadImage("assets/tp.png");
    }

    draw() {
        this.x -= 4;
         image(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

    }
}
```

From game.js

```
let score = 0;
let gameEnd = false;

class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.background = new Background();
    this.player = new Player();
    this.tp = new Tp();
    this.tps = [];
  }

  preload() {
    this.background.preload();
    this.player.preload();

  }

  setup() {
    this.player.setup();


  }


  draw() {
    this.background.draw();
    this.player.draw();

if (frameCount % 60 === 0) {
      let tp = new Tp();
      tp.preload();
      this.tps.push(new Tp ());
}

this.tps.forEach(
  (tp, index) => {
      tp.draw();
  }
)

    }
    };
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that we can run?

Comment: Turns out it was just a problem with the preload, thanks though!

Comment: @popcorn01 What was the problem?

Comment: @popcorn01 when you solve a problem, it's good to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with code and a clear description so that future visitors can benefit from the Q&A. The point is less about you solving your problem, although that's nice, and more about helping the community.